# didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL not being called in swift 2.0

Tags: swift, video, camera, video-recording

[Camera Manager](https://github.com/imaginary-cloud/CameraManager/blob/master/camera/CameraManager.swift)

Hello,

The link above is an open source library to capture image and record a video. this library was working perfectly in swift 1.2 but when they update it to swift 2.0 i couldn't recored a video so i looked around and found out that didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL protocol is not being called at all !!

please help me !!

Comment: private var tempFilePath: NSURL = {
        let tempPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("tempMovie").URLByAppendingPathExtension("mp4");
        if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(tempPath.absoluteString) {
            do {
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(tempPath.absoluteString)
            } catch {
                
            }
        }
        return tempPath
        }()

Comment: changing the return fix my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

private var tempFilePath: NSURL = { let tempPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent("tempMovie").URLByAppendingP‌​athExtension("mp4"); if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(tempPath.absoluteString) { do { try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(tempPath.absoluteString) } catch { } } return tempPath }()